# одинаковые элементы векторов Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется два вектора разной длины с неповторяющимися значениями в каждом векторе. Нужно получить значения, которые имеются одновременно в обоих векторах

```
a = np.array((1, 2, 5))
b = np.array((2, 3, 5, 10, 20))
```

Правильный результат:

```
array([2, 5])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = np.array(set(a).intersection(b))
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. `set(a)` создает из поля `а` множество.
2. На это множество применим метод `intersection(b)`, который сделает его пересечение с полем `b` (автоматически конвертированном тоже на множество).
3. Затем из этого пересечения сделаем обратно поле NumPy.

Comment: довольно медленный способ

Comment: Отличный способ, самый быстрый в подавляющем большинстве случаев.

Answer (score 2):

Есть специальный метод для этого в `Numpy`:

```py
c = np.intersect1d(a, b)
```

При работе с массивами `Numpy` лучше пользоваться его же родными методами, обычно это будет эффективнее, чем работа в чистом `Python`.

P.S. Странно, но в Google Colab получается, что чистый питон всё же быстрее. Загадочно )

```py
%timeit c = np.intersect1d(a, b)
%timeit result = np.array(set(a).intersection(b))
```

Вывод:

```
The slowest run took 10.96 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 19.6 µs per loop
The slowest run took 12.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.02 µs per loop
```

P.P.S. А, ну как обычно дело в размерах. На мелких массивах чистый питон быстрее. На очень больших массивах `Numpy` рулит.

```py
a = np.random.randint(100_000, size=500_000)
b = np.random.randint(100_000, size=500_000)
%timeit c = np.intersect1d(a, b)
%timeit result = np.array(set(a).intersection(b))
```

Вывод:

```
10 loops, best of 5: 119 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 5: 296 ms per loop
```

Comment: Спасибо, но милисекунды для меня медленно. Cupy ругается что у него нет 'intersect1d'. Через Cupy не сработает?

Comment: этот вопрос задан, т.к. имеется большой вектор, в котором по условиям определяются индексы 'ind = cp.where((a > a_min) & (a < a_max))[0]', но для оптимизации хотел убрать часть индексов, которые в дальнейшем не будут принимать участие в расчетах, поэтому хотел оставить определённые индексы, которые пересекаются с индексами условий 'ind'

Comment: @bluesky Да, судя по документации, в `cupy` этого метода нет. Но в вашем вопросе `cupy` и не упоминался )

Comment: @bluesky, быстрее будет обработать лишние индексы. Вычеркивание индексов будет быстрее только если доля лишних индексов велика (глядя на потолок - больше половины индексов всего).